# Django data saving and presenting

Tags: python, django

My Django project need to acquire one list after processing in one function of views.py.

```
def acquire(request):
    import sys
    n = []
    for topic in Topic.objects.filter(owner=request.user).order_by("date_added"):
        entries = topic.entries.all()
        q = entries.text
        n.append(q)
    return render(request, "projects/topics.html", n)
```

The list "n" above need to be transferred to another function of views.py for the information in another "results.html" page.

```
def results(request):
    data = XXXX
    return render(request, "projects/results.html", {"datas": data})
```

How could I edit "XXX" in results function to transfer the "n" list?

Comment: Is the list creation so expensive? You know you can reduce that to a single query. Other than that you can use the session or the cache (with a key identifying the user) to persist information beyond a single request-response cycle.

Comment: I'm a bit confused in transferring the data from one function to another. Not just the list itself.

Comment: You cannot think of views as functions that can be easily linked together. Only one is called per request, and since HTTP is stateless, there is no inherent way for them to share information. That's why cookies and sessions (to persist user-specific information server-side) had to be invented.

Comment: Thanks. Can you show me how to do that specifically? I need to construct one class for the data received from the first function for further processing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare the list n outside of the function so you can use it wherever you want, like:

```
n = []

def acquire(request):
    import sys
    for topic in Topic.objects.filter(owner=request.user).order_by("date_added"):
        entries = topic.entries.all()
        q = entries.text
        n.append(q)
    return render(request, "projects/topics.html", n)

def results(request):
    data = n
    return render(request, "projects/results.html", {"datas": data})
```

Comment: This is unreliable and scalable. If the worker dies between the requests, `n` won't be available and that code throws an exception.

Comment: In that case you need to create new object for maintaining all the list items and use it wherever you want this data items.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a utility function that can be used by both views and stores the data for the current session:

```
def acquire(request):
    data = _get_data(request)
    return render(request, "projects/topics.html", {'data': data})

def results(request):
    data = _get_data(request)
    return render(request, "projects/results.html", {'data': data})

# this is not a view, but a utility function
def _get_data(request)
    # this will try to use the data generated in a previous request of
    # the same session. So the data might be stale by now
    if not 'user_entries' in request.session:
        n = []
        for topic in Topic.objects\
                      .filter(owner=request.user)\
                      .order_by('date_added')\
                      .prefetch_related('entries'):  # prefetch avoids the nested queries
            for entry in topic.entries.all():
                n.append(entry.text)
        request.session['user_entries'] = n
    return request.session['user_entries']
```

Comment: Just have the error as: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'. What is the problem??

Comment: You would have to narrow that error down. Do you process `data` any further elsewhere (in the template maybe) and treat it like a `dict` or `Queryset`?

Comment: Is there any way to store the process "n" list to demonstrate it directly?

Answer (score 0):

You have to remember that whatever variable you set, it only lives within the view/function as Django is stateless. That's why you have a database and cookies.

This is how you do it. Unless that list has thousands and thousands of entries, this will be fast.

```
def results(request):
    data = []
    for topic in Topic.objects.filter(owner=request.user).order_by("date_added"):
        entries = topic.entries.all()
        q = entries.text
        data.append(q)
    return render(request, "projects/results.html", {"datas": data})
```

If you want to be really fast, you could change the request and work on the database level and create a join. Something along the lines of this (I'm a bit rusty)

```
data = Entries.objects.filter(topic__owner=request.user).order_by("topic__date_added").values("text")
```

Comment: No worries. Please don't forget to accept a reply if it answers your question. Thanks.